# Twitter OAuth callback does not seem to work in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been trying all day to connect my app to android but I'm having no luck. I've been searching for hours but all the resources I'm finding are either incomplete or outdated. I've got this so far:

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AccessToken> {

    @Override
    protected AccessToken doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("token", "here1");
        return token;
    }

}
```

The above works as far as opening the authorization page.However when I add a callback URL (as below) the app stops working. It won't even open up a browser anymore:

```
twitter.getOAuthRequestToken("myapp://callback");
```

I read somewhere I was supposed to add the below intention-filter to the manifest file. But that didn't affect the outcome:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
```

If it helps I'm using the twitter4j library.

Comment: Do some more.. checkout this project http://code.google.com/p/droidtwit/ and https://github.com/browep/Android-OAuth-Twitter-Example and https://github.com/grantland/twitter-android-sdk and also have a look at this tutorial series http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/67.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. All I had to to was insert a dummy callback URL in the app's twitter page.  Such a counter intuitive and ugly solution.